# Add Textboxes row below datagridview header

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to make a filtering system for DataGridView and want to put textbox below each header of datagridview for filtering purpose.

Comment: and what do you do for your question?!

Comment: @Amir, he is asking of how to have this effect. And regarding the answer, it should be something to do with headers, either you can *somhow* have them customized (own header class, where you can add `TextBox`) or sort of a dirty trick (making headers bigger, getting their size, putting `TextBox` control on top of it, you will definitely get into troubles with horizontal scrolling). One *cheap* possibility is to have just single `TextBox` above `DataGridView`, where you enter condition for **either** of column. Other is to just show `TextBox` shortly when you click column (to example)...

Comment: I know what he/she wants approximately but his/her question is very unclear and low quality.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is called "Auto Filter Row" where there is a row at the top of the grid that can filter each column separately.

I don't think you can do that with Microsoft's DataGridView. But you can with DevExpress Controls.
Please check this link : [Auto Filter Rows](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/CustomDocument1428).

You can try a trial version.

AnyWay, you can filter the whole table using a Textbox outside the Grid :

```
var Dt =(MyDataGridView.DataSource as DataTable)

Dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("Field = '{0}'", MyFilterTextBox.Text);
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynEGm.png)

you can write a textbox as global, and when you click the datagridview headercell, this textbox will cover the header cell.

Comment: Don't add a screenshot of your code. Add the code itself.